# How fast is MongoDB's aggregate query over 10 million entries of simple data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's say you have a database of People.

```
[
  #1 {qualities: ['brown', 'nice', 'happy' 'cool' 'cheery']}
  #2 {qualities: ['blue', 'okay', 'happy' 'decent' 'cheery']}
  #3 {qualities: ['green', 'alright', 'happy' 'cool' 'cheery']}
]
```

Here's the People **schema and model:**

```
var peopleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  qualities: [],
});

var People = mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema);
```

If you want to get data according to maximum match document then we use the **aggregate** query:

```
People.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$qualities"},
  {$match:{'qualities': {$in: ["brown", "happy", "cool"]}}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:1}}},
  {$sort:{count:-1}}
]).exec(function(err, persons) {
      console.log(persons)
});
```

it will return **1, 3,2** because for **first one** matched with *3*
 items, **third one** matched with *2* items and **second one** matched with *1* item.

### **Question**

This aggregate works fast for my database of 10,000 people - in fact, it completed this in 273.199ms. However, how will it fare for a MongoDB of 10 million entries? If these rates are proportional [100k:2.7s, 1m:27s, 10m:4m30s], it could take 4 minutes and 30 seconds. Perhaps the rate is not proportional, I do not know. But is there any optimization or suggestions for querying such a large database if my time hypothesis happens to be true?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should your *optimization* by putting the `$match` stage first in the pipeline then use `$redact` instead of  `$unwind`. From there, you can just `$sort` by `$size` of matches items in the array. You will probably not need the `$group` stage.

Comment: @Styvane thanks for the suggestion.

  Videos.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'qualities': { $in: ['brown', 'happy', 'cool'] } } },
    { $redact: '$qualities'},
    { $sort: { $size: -1 }}
  ]).exec(function(err, persons) {
    console.log(persons);
  });

Is returning undefined. Granted I have little experience with Mongo queries so please let me know what to do to fix this.

Comment: you are misanderstanding the use of $redact. Try this query: db.People.aggregate([{$match: {qualities: {$in: ["brown", "happy", "cool"]}}}, {$project: {qualities: {$filter: {input: "$qualities", as: "qualities", cond: {$or: [{$eq: ["$$qualities", "brown"]},{$eq:["$$qualities", "happy"]},{$eq: ["$$qualities", "cool"]}]}}}}}, {$project: {qualities: 1, size: {$size: "$qualities"}}}, {$sort: {size: -1}}])

Answer (score 2):

Okay. So if you have asked, 
 I will ask you to look into how the aggregate query works.

The aggregate query works on the basis of pipeline stages :
 Now, what's a `pipeline stage` :- From your example the

```
{$unwind:"$qualities"},
{$match:{'qualities': {$in: ["brown", "happy", "cool"]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$sort:{count:-1}}
```

Here, all the **unwind, match, group and sort** are pipeline stages.
The **$unwind** works by creating new documents for the embedded document (in your case **qualities**) for better nested searching.

But if you keep **$unwind** as the first stage, it creates a performance overhead by unwinding unnecessary documents. 
A  better approach would be to keep **$match** as the first stage in aggregation pipeline.

Now,  **how fast is the aggregation query** :
  The aggregation query's speed depends upon the amount of data stored into the embedded doc. If you store a million entries into the embedded doc *qualities*, it will create a performance overhead while unwinding those millions entries.

So, it all comes to how you create your database schema. Also, for faster querying you can look into the [multi key indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) and [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) approaches for mongodb.